# Error: Number of query values and destination fields are not the same - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I was looking for solutions for this error, but nothing could solve my problems. I have as many items as values in the following SQL code. I really don't know what I am doing wrong?

My access data base has following columns (eveything is a "short text" except for and ID obviously)

- ID
- eMail
- kennwort
- vorname
- nachname
- telefonnummer
- strasse
- pls
- ort
- aktivierungscode

**EDIT: I took the column that had a date out as I couldn't figure out how to implement it to the sql code... Still, I get the same error. I also added the parameters as someone suggested.**

Code:

```
public class webUser

{

private string _vorname;
private string _nachname;
private string _eMail;
private string _kennwort;

private string _strasse;
private string _plz;
private string _ort;
private string _telefonnummer;
private string _aktivierungscode;


public webUser()
{
    //
    // TODO: Add constructor logic here
    //
}
 public string eMail
{
    get { return _eMail; }
    set { _eMail= value; }
}

public string kennwort
{
    get {return kennwort; }
    set { _kennwort = value; }
}

public string vorname
{
    get { return _vorname; }
    set { _vorname = value; }
}

public string nachname
{
    get { return _nachname; }
    set { _nachname = value; }
}


public string strasse
{
    get { return _strasse; }
    set { _strasse = value; }
}

public string plz
{
    get { return _plz; }
    set { _plz = value; }
}

public string ort
{
    get { return _ort; }
    set { _ort = value; }
}

public string telefonnummer
{
    get { return _telefonnummer; }
    set { _telefonnummer = value; }
}


public string aktivierungscode
{
    get { return _aktivierungscode; }
    set { _aktivierungscode = value; }
}

public bool checkUser(string eMail)
{
    string sql = "SELECT eMail, kennwort FROM Benutzerdatenbank WHERE eMail ='" + eMail + "'";
    string conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Benutzerdatenbank.accdb");

    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conStr);
    con.Open();
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    con.Close();

    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 1)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

public bool addUser(string eMail, string kennwort)
{
    //Hinzufügen eines neuen Benutzers in der Tabelle 'tblUser'
    //Ergebniswert: WAHR=Hinzufügen hat funktioniert
    //              FALSCH=Hinzufügen hat nicht funktioniert (eMail Adresse existiert bereits in der DB)

    //1. Prüfen, ob der Benutzer bereits in der DB existiert; wenn ja => Abbruch
    if (this.checkUser(eMail) == true)
    {
        return false; //eMail existiert bereits
    }
    else
    {
        //Datensatz anlegen: eMail, passwort, enabled, aktivierungscode
        //30-stelligen-Aktivierungscode erzeugen
        string zeichen = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghjiklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
        string aktivierungscode = "";
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = 1; i < 62; i++)
        {
            aktivierungscode = aktivierungscode + zeichen.Substring(rnd.Next(0, zeichen.Length - 1), 1);
        }

        string sql = "INSERT INTO Benutzerdatenbank (eMail, kennwort, vorname, nachname, telefonnummer, strasse, plz, ort, aktivierungscode) VALUES ('" +
        eMail + "','" + kennwort + "','" + vorname + "','" + nachname + "','" + telefonnummer + "','" + "','"+ strasse + "','" + plz + "','" + ort + "','" + aktivierungscode + "');";



        //Benutzer anlegen (Datensatz in DB anfügen = INSERT-Anweisung ausführen
        string conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Benutzerdatenbank.accdb");
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conStr); //neues Verbindungsobjekt
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); //Ausführen einer Datenmanipulationsanweisung (INSERT, UPDATE; DELETE)
        con.Close();

        //Versenden des Bestätigungslinks (erst später)

        return true;
    }

}

public void ReadUser(string eMail, string kennwort)
{
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM Benutzerdatenbank WHERE eMail='" + eMail + "' AND kennwort ='" + kennwort + "'";
    string conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Benutzerdatenbank.accdb");

    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conStr);
    con.Open();
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    con.Close();

    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 1)
    {
        this.eMail = (string)ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["eMail"];
        this.vorname = (string)ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["vorname"];
        this.nachname = (string)ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["nachname"];
        this.strasse = (string)ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["strasse"];
        this.plz = (string)ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["plz"];
        this.ort = (string)ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ort"];
        this.telefonnummer = (string)ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["telefonnummer"];

    }
    else
    {
        this.eMail = "";
        this.vorname = "";
        this.nachname = "";
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please use parametrized query https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.

Comment: can you explain to me what exactly you mean? that's kinda how we did it in school... I didn't quite understand the explanation on the link tbh :/

Comment: http://xkcd.com/327/ . You should be able to find detailed explanations of the issue with building SQL queries with string concatenation by searching for "bobby tables" or "SQL injection" on your favorite search engine.

Comment: You must use parameters else the Stackoverflow.com population will suffer parallel aneurysms

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov, alright, I will check it out. Thx!

Comment: I added the whole code now @nicomp.

Answer (score 2):

You have 10 columns in `INSERT` clause and 11 values in `VALUES` clause.

I think this is the **'0'** in **kennwort + "',0,'" + vorname** is the issue.

Comment: Thank you lots, but now I get "Data type mismatch in criteria expression."

Comment: You need to validate all the column data types against data values. Please open another question with the details if the issue is not resolved. Please accept as answer if it works for you.

Comment: Uhm, excuse me, I am just in school and not have a lot of knowledge just yet. What exactly does "validate all the column data types against data values" mean? Sorry if I'm being annoying lol

Comment: For example, if a field type is number and if you are trying to insert string values, then it is data type mismatch. You can go to table definition and get data type of all 10 fields and then compare with values you are passing to see if there are such mismatches.

Comment: oh, ok I get it now. I guess the problem was the fact that I declared the date as "private string geburtsdatum" instead of "private datetime(?) geburtsdatum"... would that be correct? and if so, how can I implement it into the sql code?